# javascript making variable an element

Tags: jquery, validation, function

I would like to pass the name of the element i am playing with and then change its class. I call these functions from another function.

```
   function addErrClass(field){
        field.removeClass("valid");
        field + Info.removeClass("valid");
        field.addClass("error")
        field + Info.addClass("error");
    }
    function addValClass(field){
        field.removeClass("error");
        field + Info.removeClass("error");
        field.addClass("valid")
        field + Info.addClass("valid");
    }
```

I call these functions by

```
if(data == "yes")
          {
            addErrClass('name');
            nameInfo.text("Please choose another usename, " + checkuser + " is in use");                
          } else {
             addValClass('name');
             nameInfo.text("Awesome, " + checkuser + " is available");  
          }
```

each of the elements have been given a variable name:

```
var name = $("#nuser");     var nameInfo
   = $("#nuserInfo");   var email = $("#email");    var emailInfo =
   $("#emailInfo");
```

error received:

Uncaught TypeError: Object name has no method 'removeClass'

essentially im trying to achieve the following with each function

name.addClass
or
email.removeClass

I will be using this on lots of fields, but thought id try and keep the code to a minimum for my problem.

EDITED WITH ANSWER. THANKS

```
if(data === "yes")
{
    addErrClass(name);
    addErrClass(nameInfo);
    nameInfo.text("Please choose another usename, " + checkuser + " is in use");                
 } else {
     addValClass(name);
     addValClass(nameInfo);
     nameInfo.text("Awesome, " + checkuser + " is available");  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing 'name' which is a string into the function. Since the String type does not have a method called 'removeClass' you are receiving this error. This method only exists on jQuery objects.

Since you said you had already instantiated a variable called name that is a jQuery object, try this:

```
if(data === "yes")
{
    addErrClass(name);
    nameInfo.text("Please choose another usename, " + checkuser + " is in use");                
 } else {
     addValClass(name);
     nameInfo.text("Awesome, " + checkuser + " is available");  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be passing the string 'name' to your function instead of the variable name which contains your jquery object.  There's no removeClass method on the string object.

Comment: is this not the correct way. i assumed javascript would say, ok name is an object i can .addClass to it. thats why i have field + Info.addClass() also...i guess this not the correct practice